# Multichannel AAC mp4 encoding using libav (avconv) or ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, avconv

I am trying to create a four-channel mp4 file with AAC encoding for ambisonics use. I am trying to encode a 4-channel first-order ambisonic wav file into AAC like so:

```
avconv -i four_channel_input.wav -c:a libfaac -ac 4 four_channel_output.mp4
```

This gives me the error

```
[libfaac @ 0x7f938885a000] Specified channel_layout is not supported
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Removing the `-ac 4` option gives me a 5 channel file

```
Duration: 00:01:21.09, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 218 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) [mp4a / 0x6134706D]
  48000 Hz, 5.0, fltp, 215 kb/s (default)
```

with a blank first channel, which is obviously suboptimal. In order to create **compressed ambisonics files**, should I be using a separate format like AmbiX (even though I believe this is uncompressed)?

Comment: `libfaac` support has been removed for a number of years now, which mean you're using a very old version of ffmpeg. Upgrade to a current static git binary.

Comment: @Gyan actually I'm using libav, not ffmpeg. What's the recommended encoding method using ffmpeg?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i four_channel_input.wav -c:a aac -ac 4 -channel_layout 4.0 four_channel_output.mp4`

Comment: @Gyan Perfect! Can you add that as an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ffmpeg, you can run

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a aac -ac 4 -channel_layout 4.0 four_channel_output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this @Gyan. Solves a lot of headaches. Would really appreciate it if you could upvote the question too, if you think it's a pertinent question that will help others. I'm now onto whether this is, in fact, the best container/format for compressed ambisonic files!